# Show/Hide bottom tab navigator when scrolling

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a bottom tab bar, and I want when scrolling in the home screen to hide it exactly like `LinkedIn`.

How can this be done with smooth animation ?

Like when I scroll up and down I want to hide it (with animation) and when stop scrolling to show it again.

Also, I have a Custom Bottom Tab.

Here is my implementation:

```
<Tab.Navigator
    tabBar={(props) => <CustomBottomNavbar {...props} />}
    initialRouteName="Home"
  >
    <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
    <Tab.Screen name="Explore" component={Explorer} />
    ...
</Tab.Navigator>
```